# How to create pages with different containers using routing in ui5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a `splitapp` application using routing in `ui5`. My first page is a login page. Then the next page should be a splitapp which I am not able to do.

I am not able to navigate to the splitapp from login page using routing. My routing url is getting changed but the splitapp view is not getting loaded.

```
enter code here
// component.js

jQuery.sap.declare("sap.demo.cart.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("sap.demo.cart.Component",{
    metadata:{
        routing:{
            config:{
                viewType:"JS",
                viewPath:"shopcart",
                targetAggregation:"pages",
                clearTarget:false
            },
            routes:[
                    {
                        pattern: "",
                        name: "login",
                        view: "login",
                        viewType:"JS",
                        viewPath:"shopcart",
                        targetControl:"topMaster"
                    },
                    {
                        pattern: "splitApp",
                        name:"app",
                        view:"app",
                        targetControl:"topMaster",
                        clearTarget:false,

                        subroutes:[{
                            pattern: "master",
                            name:"master",
                            view:"master",

                            targetAggregation:"masterPages",
                            targetControl:"splitApp"
                            preservePageInSplitContainer:true
                            subroutes:[{
                                pattern:"welcome",
                                name:"welcome",
                                view:"welcome",
                                targetAggregation:"detailPages"
                            }]

                        }]
                    }
                    ]
        }
    },

    init: function(){
            jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger");
            jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler");

            sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this,arguments);
            this._router = this.getRouter();
            this._routerHandler = new  sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(this._router);
            this._router.initialize();

    },
    createContent:function(){
        var oView = sap.ui.view({
            id:"tmaster",
            viewName:"shopcart.topMaster",
            type:"JS",
            viewData:{component: this}

        });
        return oView;
 }
    });

/*login.view*/

 sap.ui.jsview("shopcart.login", {

 getControllerName : function() {
    return "shopcart.login";
},

 createContent : function(oController) {
    var opanel = new sap.m.Panel(
            {
                width:"100%",
                height:"100%",
                expandable : false,
                expanded: true,
                content:[
                    new sap.m.Panel("ologin",{
                        headerText:"Login",
                        width:"400px",
                        height:"300px",
                        content:[       
                                        new sap.m.Input("uname",{ tooltip:"Enter Username",placeholder : "Username"}),
                                        new sap.m.Input("pwd",{ type: sap.m.InputType.Password,placeholder : "Password"}),
                                        new sap.m.Link("fgt",{text:"Forgot Password?", press:oController.onForgot}),
                                        new sap.m.Button("log",{text:"Login", press:[oController.onLogin, oController]}),
                                        new sap.m.Button("clr",{text:"Clear", press:oController.onClear})
                                 ]
                    })
                 ]
    }).addStyleClass("logContainer");
    return sap.m.Page({
        content:[opanel]
    });
}
```

});

```
 /*login controller*/
sap.ui.controller("shopcart.login", {


onInit: function() {
    this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
},

onLogin: function(){
    var uname = sap.ui.getCore().byId("uname").getValue();
    var pwd = sap.ui.getCore().byId("pwd").getValue();
    if(uname=="" || pwd=="")
        {
//              openDialog(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error,"Login Details","Please provide both the username and password details to login");
        }
    else{
//          app.to("idhome2");
        this.router.navTo("app");       
    }
},
onClear:function(){
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("uname").setValue("");
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("pwd").setValue("");
},
onForgot:function(){
    openDialog(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None,"Forgot Password","Resetting is still under construction");
}
```

});

```
/*topmaster.view*/
sap.ui.jsview("shopcart.topMaster", {
createContent : function(oController) {
    return new sap.m.App("topMaster",{
    });
}
```

});

```
/*app.view*/
sap.ui.jsview("shopcart.app", {
getControllerName : function() {
    return "shopcart.app";
},
createContent : function(oController) {
    this.setDisplayBlock(true);
    return new sap.m.SplitApp("splitApp");
}
```

});

```
/*master.view*/
sap.ui.jsview("shopcart.master", { 
getControllerName : function() {
    return "shopcart.master";
},
createContent : function(oController) {
    var olist = new sap.m.List({
        mode:sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelect,
        items : [ new sap.m.StandardListItem({
              title : "Employee Master"
        }), new sap.m.StandardListItem({
             title : "Product Master"
        }),new sap.m.StandardListItem({
             title : "Category Master"
        }),new sap.m.StandardListItem({
             title : "Order Master"
        }),new sap.m.StandardListItem({
             title : "Operation Master"
        }) ]
    });
    return olist;
}
```

});

```
/*welcome.view */
sap.ui.jsview("shopcart.welcome", {

getControllerName : function() {
    return "shopcart.welcome";
},

createContent : function(oController) {
    return new sap.m.Text({text:"Welcome to Oncall Support Maintenance Fiori Application",design:sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign.H5});

}
```

});

Comment: So, how exactly did you imagine we could help you out here without showing us any code? ;-)

Comment: Add your code to get appropriate help

Comment: Sorry guys.. i have added my code now..
Now i am able to navigate to the app view page where my splitapp container loads.. but not able to add master pages and details pages into it..
Please check and assist me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code. Pay attention to the TopMaster controller and to the routing config in the Component.

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");

jQuery.sap.declare("shopcart.Component");
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend(
    "shopcart.Component",
    {
        metadata:{

            rootView : {
                viewName: "shopcart.view.TopMaster",
                type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
            },

            routing:{
                config:{
                    viewType: "JS",
                    viewPath: "shopcart.view",
                    targetControl: "topMaster",
                    targetAggregation: "pages",
                    clearTarget: false
                },
                routes: [
                    {
                        pattern: "",
                        name: "login",
                        view: "Login"
                    },
                    {
                        pattern: "splitApp",
                        name: "app",
                        view: "App",
                        subroutes:[
                            {
                                pattern: "master",
                                name: "master",
                                view: "Master",
                                targetAggregation: "masterPages",
                                targetControl: "splitApp",
                                preservePageInSplitContainer: true,
                                subroutes: [
                                    {
                                        pattern: "welcome",
                                        name: "welcome",
                                        view: "Welcome",
                                        targetControl: "splitApp",
                                        targetAggregation: "detailPages"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        init: function(){

            sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(
                this,
                arguments
            );
            var oRouter = this.getRouter();
            oRouter.initialize();

        }
    }
);

// <-- TopMaster.view.js -->
sap.ui.jsview(
    "shopcart.view.TopMaster",
    {
        getControllerName : function() {
            return "shopcart.controller.TopMaster";
        },

        createContent : function(oController) {
            return new sap.m.App(
                "topMaster"
            );
        }
    }
);

// <-- TopMaster.controller.js -->
sap.ui.controller(
    "shopcart.controller.TopMaster",
    {

        onInit: function() {

            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);

        },

        onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {

            var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();
            var oView = this.getView();
            var oApp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("topMaster");

            if (oApp.getCurrentPage().sId !== oParameters.view.sId) {
                oApp.to(oParameters.view.sId);
            }

        }

    }
);


// <-- login.view -->
sap.ui.jsview(
    "shopcart.view.Login",
    {
        getControllerName : function() {
            return "shopcart.controller.Login";
        },

        createContent : function(oController) {

            return new sap.m.Page(
                {   
                    title: "Login",
                    content: [
                        new sap.m.Panel(
                            {
                                width:"100%",
                                height:"100%",
                                expandable : false,
                                expanded: true,
                                content:[
                                    new sap.m.Panel(
                                        "ologin",
                                        {
                                            headerText:"Login",
                                            width:"400px",
                                            height:"300px",
                                            content:[       
                                                new sap.m.Input(
                                                    this.createId("uname"),
                                                    {
                                                        tooltip: "Enter Username",
                                                        placeholder: "Username"
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                                new sap.m.Input(
                                                    this.createId("pwd"),
                                                    {
                                                        type: sap.m.InputType.Password,
                                                        placeholder: "Password"
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                                new sap.m.Link(
                                                    this.createId("fgt"),
                                                    {
                                                        text:"Forgot Password?",
                                                        press: oController.onForgot
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                                new sap.m.Button(
                                                    this.createId("log"),
                                                    {
                                                        text:"Login",
                                                        press:[
                                                            oController.onLogin,
                                                            oController
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                                new sap.m.Button(
                                                    this.createId("clr"),
                                                    {
                                                        text:"Clear",
                                                        press:oController.onClear
                                                    }
                                                )
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    )
                                ]
                            }
                        )
                        .addStyleClass("logContainer")
                    ]
                }
            );
        }
    }
);

// <-- Login.controller.js -->
sap.ui.controller(
    "shopcart.controller.Login",
    {

        onInit: function() {
            
        },

        onLogin: function(){
            var oView = this.getView();
            var sUsername = oView.byId("uname").getValue();
            var sPassword = oView.byId("pwd").getValue();

            if( sUsername === "" || sPassword === ""){
                sap.m.MessageBox.alert(
                    "Please provide your login details",
                    {
                        title: "Error"
                    }
                );
            }
            else{
                var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                oRouter.navTo("welcome");
            }
        },

        onClear:function(){
            var oView = this.getView();
            oView.byId("uname").setValue(null);
            oView.byId("pwd").setValue(null);
        },

        onForgot:function(){
            sap.m.MessageBox.alert(
                "Resetting is still under construction",
                {
                    title: "Error"
                }
            );
        }
    }
);

// <-- App.view.js -->
sap.ui.jsview(
    "shopcart.view.App",
    {
        getControllerName : function() {
            return "shopcart.controller.App";
        },
        createContent : function(oController) {
            this.setDisplayBlock(true);
            return new sap.m.SplitApp(
                "splitApp"
            );
        }
    }
);

// <-- App.controller.js -->
sap.ui.controller(
    "shopcart.controller.App",
    {

        onInit: function() {

        }

    }
);

// <-- Master.view.js -->
sap.ui.jsview(
    "shopcart.view.Master",
    { 
        getControllerName : function() {
            return "shopcart.controller.Master";
        },
        createContent : function(oController) {
            return new sap.m.List(
                {
                    mode:sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelect,
                    items : [
                        new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                            {
                                title : "Employee Master"
                            }
                        ),
                        new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                            {
                                title : "Product Master"
                            }
                        ),
                        new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                            {
                                title : "Category Master"
                            }
                        ),
                        new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                            {
                                title : "Order Master"
                            }
                        ),
                        new sap.m.StandardListItem(
                            {
                                title : "Operation Master"
                            }
                        )
                    ]
                }
            );
        }
    }
);

// <-- Master.controller.js -->
sap.ui.controller(
    "shopcart.controller.Master",
    {

        onInit: function() {
            
        }

    }
);

// <-- Welcome.view.js -->
sap.ui.jsview(
    "shopcart.view.Welcome",
    {

        getControllerName : function() {
            return "shopcart.controller.Welcome";
        },

        createContent : function(oController) {
            return new sap.m.Text(
                {
                    text: "Welcome to Oncall Support Maintenance Fiori Application"
                }
            );
        }

    }
);

// <-- Welcome.controller.js -->
sap.ui.controller(
    "shopcart.controller.Welcome",
    {

        onInit: function() {
            
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, its working..thanks a lot!!.. one last thing, i would like to know where i went wrong and how this routing works.. i am using routing for the first time so.. it would be helpful if you could explain

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
        <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->

        <script>
            function Login(){
                        **window.location.assign("dashboard.html#/dashboard");**
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content">
        <div id="content-center-alignment">
        <div class="inner">
        <img alt="" src="">
            <input id="txtUsername" type="text" placeholder="Enter user name"></input>
            <br/>
            <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password"></input>
                        <br/>
            <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" onClick="Login();" class="button">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

just add **stared line in your index.html by doing this you can able to redirect to another view from index.html